# jqplot tooltip not working for large number of x axis data labels

Tags: tooltip, jqplot, jqplot-highlighter

I am rendering a bar chart in my code but since I have too many x axis data points, the tooltip doesnt show. Can anyone help here?

My code is:

```
plot = $.jqplot(chartID, [xAndyVals],
{
    title: tempKey,
    seriesDefaults: {
        pointLabels: { show: true },
    },
    series: [{ renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer }],
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: -30,
            fontSize: '10pt',
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            ticks: xTicks,
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: yMaxVal,
        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 7.5,
        tooltipContentEditor: tooltipContentEditor
    },
    cursor: {
        show: false,
        showTooltip: true
    },
});


function tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
    var plotData = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex];
    var tooltip = mapping.get(plotData[0]);
    return tooltip + ", " + plotData[1];
}
```

Sample `xAndyVals` is `[0, 152518]`, where `0` is the x axis value and `152158` is the y axis value.

Comment: can you provide some sample values for `xAndyVals` variable. Also share your `tooltipContentEditor` function also. Thats makes it easier to debug for us.

Comment: Sure. Sample values for xAndyVals is

xAndyVals[0] = [0, 152158]
xAndyVals[1] = [1, 110859]
Here the first value is the x axis value and the 2nd is the y axis value.

My tooltipContentEditor function is:

    //The tooltipContentEditor is used to modify the content of the tooltips so that the tooltips show the non-truncated values of the x-axis labels
    function tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
        var plotData = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex];
        var tooltip = mapping.get(plotData[0]);
        return tooltip + ", " + plotData[1];
    }

Comment: When i debug the code, it doesnt hit the tooltipContent editor function

Comment: please edit your question and place this info. So that its easy for everyone to know about this. If you provide the complete code with the values of all the variables inside your code then it is easy to work on. You have lot of variable in your code, where i dont know what kind of values to assume.
Thanks

Comment: the question has been edited